# Integrating SharePoint 2013 on premises with angular 4 in visual studio

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, angularjs

How can I integrate SharePoint 2013 on premises with Angular 4 in Visual Studio?
How to include my custom html template in the home page?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following:

1. Created Angular solution using your favorite IDE outside SharePoint
2. Uploaded Angular files to /_catalogs/masterpage/myangularapp
3. Added Content Editor Web Part to SharePoint page and point web part to the Angular app like /_catalogs/masterpage/myangularapp/index.html